# JFace TreeViewer to save the state of tree node when expanded/collapsed

Tags: java, swt, jface

How can I persist the state of the collapsed/expanded tree nodes?

I thought of using the `addTreeListener` to retrieve the expandedTreePaths from a `TreeViewer` and save that details, which is a `TreePath[]`, by using the `IMemento`. So I have to transform the `TreePath[]` to a `String`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you can use `getExpandedTreePaths()` to obtain an array of expanded tree paths. I don't see why a `TreeListener` would be necessary. It is sufficient to get all expanded elements when saving the tree state is requested.

The `segments` of the `TreePath` consist of your domain objects, i.e. the ones returned from your content provider. Hence you should choose an approach for serializing and deserializing that is suitable for your domain model.

Comment: I see what you mean, I removed the TreeListener